# Does DataWindow .NET use connection pooling?

Tags: .net, sybase, connection-pooling, powerbuilder

Does or can DataWindow .NET take advantage of connection pooling?

Comment: @Colin Pickard.  Thanks for adding the datawindow.net tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember (I stopped coding in PB just before the mainstream upgrade to 12.0 which had all the .NET goodies), yes it can. Basically, you have to set your DW up to use an AdoTransaction, which interfaces with ADO.NET, instead of the PB-native Transaction (the classic method, which AFAIK does not allow pooling). Then, you use the standard configuration on the ADO.NET side to manage connection pooling like you would if you were developing in C# or VB.Net.